# Java Tika cannot get embedded files from rar file

Tags: java, apache-tika

With the standard implementation, I pass a doc file, inside of which there is an image.png image and text.

With the standard implementation, I pass a doc file, inside of which there is an image.png image and text

In order to get the files, Tika uses the internal **ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor** class, inside which the **parseEmbedded** method is used.

First I implement the necessary elements and call the parse method:

```
//other objects
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); 
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
Tika tika = new Tika();
BodyContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1); 
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/sample.txt"));

//using
parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc);
```

Next, if Tika selects the right parser and the **ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor** class is called inside it, namely its **parseEmbedded** method.

With this approach, if my input data is a file: 1.docx , then at the output I can see:

```
1.docx
 -image.png
 -text
```

Or if the input file is: 222.rar , then at the output I have:

```
222.rar
  -1.docx
    -image.png
    -text
```

At the same time, to control the process of extracting parts, it was decided to redefine the **ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor** class, with its key method **parseEmbedded**.

It turns out that we create a **CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor** and save it in the Tika configuration so that it replaces the original **ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor** class:

```
CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor customEmbeddedDocExtractor = new CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(pc);
pc.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, customEmbeddedDocExtractor);
```

At the same time, I do not make any changes inside the new class and inside its **parseEmbedded** method.

When testing a new class on the same input data, we get the following output:

```
1) input file: 1.doc

output: 
1.doc
 -image.png
 -text


2) inputfile: 222.rar

222.rar
  1.doc
```

Comparing the work of the two classes, we get the following result:

```
Result from ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor:
input file: 222.rar

output:
222.rar
  -1.docx
    -image.png
    -text

Result from CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor:
input file: 222.rar

output:
222.rar
  -1.docx
```

When using this new class, it is not possible to get the objects I need from the **222.rar/1.docx** file - an image and text. At the same time, if you use the old ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor class, you can get these elements.

---

It is not clear what caused such a discrepancy in the results, if only because I am just creating exactly the same class and saving it in place of a new one. I am not making changes to my new class, and at the same time I get a different output result.

---

Please tell me why Tika can't get the data with this approach? Maybe someone has already encountered a similar situation, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the RecursiveParserWrapper?  To see what the output looks like, use the -J commandline option with tika-app or the /rmeta endpoint in tika-server.  If the output is what you want, then you can follow examples from our unit tests to see how to use it: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-parsers/tika-parsers-standard/tika-parsers-standard-package/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/parser/RecursiveParserWrapperTest.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the full operation of the CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor class, it is necessary

1. save the class to the configuration (in class ParseContext pc)
2. save the desired parser to the configuration (in our case, parser is a class AutoDetectParser parser)

Therefore, instead of such an implementation:

```
CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor customEmbeddedDocExtractor = new CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(pc);
pc.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, customEmbeddedDocExtractor);
```

We need such an implementation:

```
if (pc.get(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class) == null) {
    Parser p = pc.get(Parser.class);
    if (p == null) {
        pc.set(Parser.class, parser);
    }
                    
    CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor customEmbeddedDocExtractor = new CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(pc);
    pc.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, customEmbeddedDocExtractor);
}
```